# Automatically run Pelican on system boot

Tags: server, startup, webserver

I'm running [Pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com) on my server to generate static html pages for my website.

I can log in to my server via SSH, navigate to the directory where the my site files are stored (source in markdown) and issue the following command :

```
pelican content -r -s publishconf.py
```

This will keep Pelican running and watching for changes, which is great as I can now upload new articles and my site is updated automatically.

I'd like this command to be run at system startup, in case I ever need to reboot.  How can I achieve that?  I'm new to Linux, so a step-by-step example would be great.

Comment: When you start Pelican does it go to the background immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Upstart job should do the trick. Create a file in `/etc/init` (say `/etc/init/pelican.conf`), containing:

```
description "Pelican"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /path/to/site/files
exec pelican content -r -s publishconf.py
```

Of course, this will run as root. If you usually run Pelican as another user (say `patrick`), add:

```
setuid patrick
```

before the `exec` line.

You can the start the job immediately with `service pelican start`.